# How do I connect to an ASMX web service in vs2012

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, windows-store-apps

I am currently new in developing. I am trying to connect web service in my windows store project.

In this code don't have error but it didn't respond any thing. is it I want use another code or put some message box to called result from web service?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Windows8App
{

public sealed partial class Login : Page
{  
    public Login()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private async void loginAsync(string username, string password)
    {
          ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient service = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
          var response = service.loginwebAsync(username, password);
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          string user = txtUsername.Text;
          string pass = txtPassword.Text;

          System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
          {
              loginAsync(user, pass);
          });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the code here, not on an external site. And please describe your problem in more detail; what have you tried to fix it? What diagnostics have you tried?

Comment: Please provide us more information about the situation. What have you tryed so far? what is not working? etc.

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: Actually, I want call database from webservie for USER to login. If user click "Login" button, it will show the result. I trying many methods for called web service but it have error. For example(the website link):    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/12/21/help-me-how-do-i-connect-to-an-asmx-web-service.aspx      http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/160f7c96-7b55-4bfb-96d3-55c4b80ff843.html

Comment: My app can't use this code -> Console.WriteLine("The result is:");It is use this, it have error and display "The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context."

Answer (score 0):

Your service call lacks `await` keyword. Re-write your code like this. If it works please mark it as answer otherwise I'll delete my answer.

```
private async Task loginAsync(string username, string password)
{
      ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient service = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
      var response = await service.loginwebAsync(username, password);
}

private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      string user = txtUsername.Text;
      string pass = txtPassword.Text;

      await loginAsync(user, pass);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Xyroid. Is it I need to put message box to call result from web service? Actually,I already set in my web services database If user click "Login" button, it will show user ID. If user no record in database and click "Login button", it will show "you are not in record."

Comment: You have to use [`MessageDialoge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208674) in app to show the response.